# spring kafka config in bootstrap.yml can not work

Tags: spring-kafka

spring kafka config bootstrap.yml not work.

I used application.yml instead of bootstrap.yml . it works now.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
```

Why spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer in bootstrap.yml was not work?

Comment: Your props helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply change the name of properties/yml file.

**If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or file paths). The following example shows how to specify a different file name:**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files